# Conditional formatting displaying correctly in SPD but not in page

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-designer, formatting

I have been attempting to create status indicators in Sharpeoint Designer 2010 using two background images (red and green circles) in a hyperlink column and conditional formatting.
The idea is that the hyperlinks direct to a list and the background image indicates the status of that list.
I have been using the xsl:choose element to pick which cirle gets displayed behind the hyperlink.

```
<xsl:attribute name="style">
    <xsl:choose>
       <xsl:when test="$thisNode/@prodimpnumber != '1'" xmlns:ddwrt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebParts/v2/DataView/runtime" ddwrt:cf_explicit="1"> background-image: url(&apos;../images1/red indicator small.png&apos;); background-repeat: no-repeat; background-position: center center; line-height: 100px; vertical-align: middle; text-align: center;
       </xsl:when>
       <xsl:otherwise> background-position: center center; background-image: url(&apos;../images1/green indicatorsmall.png&apos;); background-repeat: no-repeat; vertical-align: middle; text-align: center; line-height: 100px; font-weight: bold;
       </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:attribute>
```

My issue is this: in sharepoint designer the indicators display properly in SPD i.e. display green cicle if the relevant column isn't equal 1 and otherwise display red circle,
however on the actual page only green circles are displayed.
Here how the indicators look in SPD
[image: SPD display of status indicators]

Here is how the page looks 
[image]

I can't figure out what's happening or how to fix it. Assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could replicate this behavior, so I'm afraid you have missing the reference for the "**prodimpnumber**" column on the **View** properties.

I made a similar condition criteria mentioning "**Column1**", and then I comment the reference like following:

```
<View Name="{0C5D6622-FA99-4D41-9F5B-BC61F040CD83}........>
                        <Query/>
                        <ViewFields>
                            <FieldRef Name="LinkTitle"/>
                            <!-- <FieldRef Name="Column1"/> -->
                            <FieldRef Name="Column2"/>
                            <FieldRef Name="Column3"/>
                            <FieldRef Name="Column4"/>
                            <FieldRef Name="Column5"/>
                        </ViewFields>
                    </View>
```

---

```
<xsl:if test="$thisNode/@Column1 != '1'">background-color: #FF9966;</xsl:if>
```

After this I still see a correct behavior on SPD but when I published the page it just didn't show the sytle on browser.

Hope it helps,
Regards

Comment: This worked. Turns out like your post suggested the reference was missing. Thank you very much agzertuche